# Adding a line to the beginning of every function in a (ruby) source code file

Tags: regular-expressions

Supposed I have a source code file (classes) and some methods in that file.

see
https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb

I want to add a "debug print" statement to the begining of every function.

So

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
```

should end up looking like

```
  def new
    Rails.logger.debug "DEBUGTRACE1"
    @user = User.new
  end
```

How would emacsens do something like this quickly?
I am mildly familiar with regexps thanks to perl training.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple job with `M-x replace-regexp` (or `C-M-%` which is `query-replace-regexp`, press `!` to change all occurrences). Assuming that all function definitions start with a line that starts with `def` and that the logging statement should be added immediately below, replace

```
^\( *\)def .*
```

by

```
\&
\1  Rails.logger.debug "DEBUGTRACE1"
```

In the replacement text, press `C-q C-j` to insert the line break after `\&`. `\&` stands for the original text matching the regular expression. `\1` stands for the part inside backslash-parentheses, which is the indentation of the `def` line.

If you want to include the function name in the trace, arrange to put it in a second backslash-parentheses group. Something like:

```
^\( *\)def \(\w+\).*
```

by

```
\&
\1  Rails.logger.debug "trace from \2"
```